# Joining dataframes without ON clause but with multiple column condition and populate flag in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join 2 dataframes and retrieve ID from A by matching with some column conditions. Basically I have to fill '0' s in B with ID's from A and I don't have an ON clause for this, so I may need a cross join, but the thing is I would need only B set.

Below are my test data written in pyspark

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, count, col, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# Create the two dataframes
B = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(0,'Sam',100,'ind','IT','2/11/2019'),
                                          (0,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                 (0,'Kom',3500,'uk','IT','2/11/2019'),
                                          (0,'Nom',4000,'can','HR','2/11/2019'),
                                 (0,'Vom',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019'),
                                          (0,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT','2/11/2019')],
                                 ['ID','AName','ASal','BAddress','CDept','DJoin_Date'])
A = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',100,'ind','ITA','2/11/2019'),(22,'Tom',2000,'usa','HRA','2/11/2019'),
                                  (33,'Kom',3000,'uuk','ITA','2/11/2019'),(44,'Nom',4000,'can','HRA','2/11/2019'),
                                  (55,'Xum',5000,'mex','ITA','2/11/2019'),(77,'XYZ',5000,'mex','ITA','2/11/2019')],
                                 ['ID','AName','ASal','BAddress','CDept','DJoin_Date'])
A.show()
B.show()
```

1. I need to join 2 dataframes
2. if(B.AName= A.Aname and B.ASal= A.ASal ) then I need to fetch ID and put them in B.ID and generate an indicator column with value 'case1'
3. if(B.AName= A.Aname and B.ASal= A.ASal )and (B.BAddress= A.BAddress ) then I need to fetch ID and put them in B.ID and generate an indicator column with value 'case1 and case2'

Expected output is

```
ID,AName,ASal,BAddress,CDept,DJoin_Date,indicator
11,Sam,100,ind,IT,2/11/2019,case1 and case2
22,Tom,2000,usa,HR,2/11/2019,case1 and case2
33,Kom,3500,uk,IT,2/11/2019,case1
44,Nom,4000,can,HR,2/11/2019,case1 and case2
0,Vom,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019,
77,XYZ,5000,mex,IT,2/11/2019,case1 and case2
```

What will be the best way to do this.For the conditional check I was trying to use udf in withColumn, but there also I will need to return 2 values (ID and indicator). So I think udf will not work in this case

Update 1

---

One more doubt connected with same question. I don't want to create another thread for this. So asking here.

Say I have one more column in both df ie
ID,AName,ASal,BAddress,CDept,DJoin_Date,ID2

If Name and sal matched,B.ID should contain the value of A.ID,but
If address is getting matched instead of Replacing B.ID with A.ID, I need to replace them with B.ID2 = A.ID2

Will I be able to do it in same select query.
By getting indicator flag value? Something like, if indicator == case 1 and case2,then replace B.ID2=A.ID2.
But will new indicator column in select statement be available to do that conditional check(as indicator column is not part of A or B dataframe)?

Update 2

---

Made few changes in the dataset

```
  import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, count, col, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# Create the two dataframes
B = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(0,'Sam',100,'ind','IT',0),
                                          (0,'Tom',2000,'usa','HR',30),
                                 (0,'Kom',3500,'uk','IT',-8),
                                          (0,'XYZ',5000,'mex','IT',25)],
                                 ['ID','AName','ASal','BAddress','CDept','ID2'])
A = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(11,'Sam',100,'Korea','ITA',500),(22,'Jack',2000,'usa','HRA',4500),
                                  (33,'Kom',3500,'uk','ITA',5009)],
                                 ['ID','AName','ASal','BAddress','CDept','ID2'])

df = B.join(A, ['AName', 'ASal'], 'left').select(
    F.coalesce(A.ID, B.ID).alias('ID'),
    'AName',
    'ASal',
    B.BAddress,
    B.CDept,
    F.when(
        A.ID.isNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress),
        'case2'
    ).when(
        A.ID.isNotNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress),
        'case1 and case2'
    ).when(
        A.ID.isNotNull(),
        'case1'
    ).alias('indicator'),
    F.when(
        A.ID.isNotNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress),
        A.ID2
    ).otherwise(B.ID2).alias('ID2')
)
```

Output

```
  +---+-----+----+--------+-----+---------------+----+
| ID|AName|ASal|BAddress|CDept|      indicator| ID2|
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+---------------+----+
| 33|  Kom|3500|      uk|   IT|case1 and case2|5009|
| 11|  Sam| 100|     ind|   IT|          case1|   0|
|  0|  XYZ|5000|     mex|   IT|           null|  25|
|  0|  Tom|2000|     usa|   HR|           null|  30|
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+---------------+----+
```

Expected output

```
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+---------------+----+
| ID|AName|ASal|BAddress|CDept|      indicator| ID2|
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+---------------+----+
| 33|  Kom|3500|      uk|   IT|case1 and case2|5009|
| 11|  Sam| 100|     ind|   IT|          case1|   0|
|  0|  XYZ|5000|     mex|   IT|           null|  25|
|  0|  Tom|2000|     usa|   HR|           **case2|  4500**|
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+---------------+----+
```

1. I need to join 2 dataframes
2. if(B.AName= A.Aname and B.ASal= A.ASal ) then I need to fetch ID and put them in B.ID and generate an indicator column with value 'case1'

3.if(B.BAddress= A.BAddress ) then I need to fetch A.ID2 and put them in B.ID2 and generate an indicator column with value 'case2'
4. if(B.AName= A.Aname and B.ASal= A.ASal )and (B.BAddress= A.BAddress ) then I need to fetch ID and put them in B.ID and generate an indicator column with value 'case1 and case2'

I am trying to achieve 3rd point. But it is returning null

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left join on AName and ASal, and get the indicator using `when` to check if A.ID is null (which indicates no matches on AName and ASal). If it is not null, it means there is a match, then you can assign the indicator on whether the address matches.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = B.join(A, ['AName', 'ASal'], 'left').select(
    F.coalesce(A.ID, B.ID).alias('ID'),
    'AName',
    'ASal',
    B.BAddress,
    B.CDept,
    B.DJoin_Date,
    F.when(
        A.ID.isNotNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress),
        'case1 and case2'
    ).when(
        A.ID.isNotNull(),
        'case1'
    ).alias('indicator')
).orderBy('ID')

df.show()
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+----------+---------------+
| ID|AName|ASal|BAddress|CDept|DJoin_Date|      indicator|
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+----------+---------------+
|  0|  Vom|5000|     mex|   IT| 2/11/2019|           null|
| 11|  Sam| 100|     ind|   IT| 2/11/2019|case1 and case2|
| 22|  Tom|2000|     usa|   HR| 2/11/2019|case1 and case2|
| 33|  Kom|3500|      uk|   IT| 2/11/2019|          case1|
| 44|  Nom|4000|     can|   HR| 2/11/2019|case1 and case2|
| 77|  XYZ|5000|     mex|   IT| 2/11/2019|case1 and case2|
+---+-----+----+--------+-----+----------+---------------+
```

If you have one more ID2 column, you can do something like

```
df = B.join(A, ['AName', 'ASal'], 'left').select(
    F.coalesce(A.ID, B.ID).alias('ID'),
    'AName',
    'ASal',
    B.BAddress,
    B.CDept,
    B.DJoin_Date,
    F.when(
        A.ID.isNotNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress),
        'case1 and case2'
    ).when(
        A.ID.isNotNull(),
        'case1'
    ).alias('indicator'),
    F.when(
        A.ID.isNotNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress),
        B.ID2
    ).otherwise(A.ID2)
)
```

Comment: Yes that's correct. But can we make this little more generic, means say there is a 4th condition to match -if(B.AName= A.Aname and B.ASal= A.ASal )and (B.BAddress= A.BAddress ) and (B.CDept = A.CDept) then I need to fetch ID and put them in B.ID and generate an indicator column with value 'case1 and case2 and case3'. In that case how can we achieve this. This is not in my question (may be I can add that). I am trying to learn a generic solution for this.

Comment: You can simply chain more `when` conditions. Is that what you want?

Comment: Oh yes got it. if I need to set indicator as case1  and case2 and case 3,then I have to add one more when,when(
        A.ID.isNotNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress) & (B.CDept = A.CDept),
        'case1 and case2 and case3'

Comment: why did I thought of UDF and cross joins and made it so complicated...Thanks mck. I will work this out and accept your answer.

Comment: Updated question with one more doubt

Comment: See if the edited answer helps? @UnmeshaSreeVeni

Comment: Yes that helps. I was also trying to get - if not (B.AName= A.Aname and B.ASal= A.ASal ) then match Address and set indicator as case 2. I tried coding A.ID.isNull() & (B.BAddress == A.BAddress) but I am getting Resolved attribute(s)  BAddress missing error. So here A.ID is null, which means we have the unmatchedrecords,are we not able to get the rest of the column values with that condition?

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't happen. Could you show the code you used by editing your question?

Comment: I could resolve that attribute issue. But still the address is not getting matched ,not sure if coding went wrong somewhere

Comment: I think you should use `A.ID.isNotNull()` , not `B.ID.isNotNull()`

Comment: Tried that. import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = B.join(A, ['ID', 'AName'], 'left').select(
    B.ID,B.AName,
    F.coalesce(A.ASal, B.ASal).alias('ASal'),#ID and Name Matched
    B.BAddress,
    B.CDept,
   F.when(
        (A.ID.isNotNull() & A.AName.isNotNull()) & ((B.BAddress == A.BAddress) & (B.CDept == A.CDept)),
        A.ID2
    ).otherwise(B.ID2).alias('ID2').Then I am getting  'Resolved attribute(s) ID#36 missing from ID2#29L,ASal#26L,BAddress#27,AName#25,BAddress#39,CDept#40,ASal#38L,ID#24,ID2#41L,CDept#28 in operator

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you're joining on ID.  why don't you join on name and sal? like in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229044/discussion-between-unmesha-sreeveni-and-mck).